# Remember grid filter state between requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

I'm using Telerik asp.net mvc extensions. 
In my application in most cases I'm using the following flow:

1. Show Grid
2. Click on the button and perfom business action
3. Redirect back to Grid.

The problem is that when the user chose some filter in 1. then this filter is lost in 3. Additionally it is kind of annoying when the user chooses from the menu action to show grid and the last used filter is not applied.

Grid filters are stored in URL (GET method).

Such as:

http://localhost/IncomingRequest?IncomingRequestGrid-page=1&IncomingRequestGrid-orderBy=IncomingDate-desc&IncomingRequestGrid-groupBy=~&IncomingRequestGrid-filter=IncomingDate~gt~datetime'2011-10-20T08-10-11'~and~CartNumber~endswith~'xx'

What I would want is to remember filter state between requests. Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [this](http://www.telerik.com/account/support-tickets/view-ticket.aspx?threadid=465579) thread. you can persist filter sorting and paging. The solution is for ajax binding for server binding you may follow [this](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-mvc/grid/preserve-grid-state-between-pages.aspx) post

Comment: Thank you very much! This link inspired me to implement my solution!.